# fopen/fwrite -> how can I confirm that the process went through, or throw an error

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is query a database and write a file with the contents of the columns.  The code below works, but I have some questions...

```
$Query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '". $variable ."' LIMIT 1");
    while ($Var = $Query->fetch_assoc()) {

$string = '<?php
$one = "'. $Var['Column1'] .'";
$two = "'. $Var['Column2'] .'";
$three = "'. $Var['Column3'] .'"; 
?>';

$fp = fopen("validate.php", "w");
echo fwrite($fp, $string);
fclose($fp);


    }  // while loop for license query
```

1) Is there a way to find out if the fopen/fwrite succeeds or fails? Not sure if there is any error handling with this.  I want to display a success message or fail message on the page once it processes.  I know I can do this based on the mysqli statement, but wanted to find out if I could do this based on the fopen/fwrite.

2) When I visit the page it is located on..it is outputting '80' on the page.  This is the only code on the page.  It is getting the data from the table, writing the file, and then just displaying "80" on the page.  Why does it do this?  I'm guessing this is related to the fopen/fwrite script...but not exactly sure.

Any suggestions on improvements are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php, `fopen` returns a FALSE if the file is not opened.

You are outputting 80 because you are echoing the result of your `fwrite`, which results the number of bytes written or FALSE on error.